# "NoMethodError: undefined method `specificity' for [:not(.block-layered-nav)]:Array"

Tags: magento, sass, compass-sass

This is in addition to this post: [Can't compile rwd skin SCSS in Magento CE 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626558/cant-compile-rwd-skin-scss-in-magento-ce-1-9)

```
Windows 8.1 / PowerShell
Compass 1.0.1 (Polaris)
Sass 3.4.6 (Selective Steve)
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x64-mingw32]
```

I removed the " from a:not(".button") > a:not(.button)

New error:

```
"NoMethodError: undefined method `specificity' for [:not(.block-layered-nav)]:Array";
```

Commented out the block then I get:

```
"NoMethodError: undefined method `specificity' for [:not(:last-child)]:Array"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This appears to be a [known issue with Sass 3.4.6](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1476).  You'll need to downgrade to 3.4.5 until this is fixed.

Comment: Considering that most people will have installed Compass and not SASS directly, which version of Compass correlates to SASS 3.4.5?

Comment: @pspahn As long as you're using Compass 1.0 or newer, it should be compatible with any version of Sass 3.3 or newer.  So if you're doing a fresh install of Compass, it will just grab the newest stable version of Sass.

Comment: @cimmanon Thanks - I just needed to: `gem uninstall sass` then `gem install sass -v 3.4.5` All good.

Comment: as @pspahn said:  gem uninstall sass && gem install sass -v 3.4.5 works, try with sudo if you require it