# Gulp Compass broke down after Sass update 3.4.6

Tags: gulp, osx-yosemite, compass, gulp-sass

When my gulp runs compass over my sass file I run into the following error:

```
error src/scss/site/style.scss (/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.6/lib/sass/selector/abstract_sequence.rb:96:in `block in _specificity': undefined method `specificity' for [:not(.pointer)]:Array)
```

I don't know what this error means exactly, but the file it's pointed to has no special source, it's just a small legit scss file:

```
@import '../general';

.tld {
  color: $color-primary;
}
```

I also keep getting these errors in my Gulp streams, it might be related:

```
[21:45:01] Ignoring psych-2.0.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine psych-2.0.6

[21:45:01] Ignoring ffi-1.9.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi-1.9.5
```

Of course I tried the "gem pristine" but that doesn't do anything.

I don't know what happened all I know is that my gulpfile was the same last week and it worked flawlessly. I installed OSX Yosemite and didn't do anything special.

I know my description lacks stuff, but that's because I don't have a clue where to look for a solution, because I don't understand the error.

Comment: It appears a sass update broke down sass. Reverting back to previous version should do the job

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento CE 1.9 - SCSS / Compass compile error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431889/magento-ce-1-9-scss-compass-compile-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I was blaming my OSX Yosemite upgrade but this was not right. I also upgraded my gems and it appears my sass upgrade to 3.4.6 broke down sass. Downgrading to 3.4.5 does the job:

```
sudo gem uninstall sass

sudo gem install sass --version 3.4.5
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. Still getting:
gulp-ruby-sass stderr: Error: Undefined mixin 'transition'. 
Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is just a regular sass error. This has nothing to do with the issue above. But have you tried adding @import "compass/css3/transition" to your sass file?

Comment: I had this problem using Sencha Touch 2.4.2 and trying to update a theme. Downgrading from 3.4.6 to 3.4.5 worked.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me without downgrading anything:

```
gem pristine --all
```

Ref:
http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-pristine

Answer (score 0):

SASS 3.4.5 will fix it:

```
sudo gem install sass --version 3.4.5
```

Also recommended is switching to using [`node-sass`](https://github.com/sass/node-sass), as the `libsass` bindings are much cleaner to work with.